# Help Writing a Simple Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, class

**How in the WORLD do I write a test class around this code? I've been able to get a successful test run, but the test says I have no code coverage. All this code does is take 5 text inputs passed in from Visualforce and post them to Chatter for all to see.**

```
public with sharing class ChatterPostController{

    public String detail {get; set;}
    public String detail2 {get; set;}
    public String detail3 {get; set;}
    public String detail4 {get; set;}
    public String detail5 {get; set;}
    public Id groupId {get;set;}

    public PageReference doPost() {

        FeedItem fitem = new FeedItem();

        groupId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        fItem.parentId=groupId;
        fItem.body= 'Air Temperature: ' + detail + '\r\n' + 'Pavement Temperature: ' + detail2 + '\r\n' + 'Inches of Rain: ' + detail3 + '\r\n' + 'Inches of Snow: ' + detail4 + '\r\n' + 'Comment: ' + detail5;

        insert fItem;

        PageReference pageRef = ApexPages.currentPage();

        return null;
    }
}
```

Help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you post what you have so far and we can help you move it forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its only the Apex (and not the Visualforce) that can be tested. So you invoke the class in your test and then assert what happens:

```
@isTest
private class ChatterPostControllerTest {

    @isTest
    static void test() {

        ChatterPostController c = new ChatterPostController();
        c.detail = 'd';
        c.detail2 = 'd2';
        c.detail3 = 'd3';
        c.detail4 = 'd4';
        c.detail5 = 'd5';
        c.doPost();

        FeedItem[] items = [select ParentId, Body from FeedItem];
        System.assertEquals(1, items.size());
        FeedItem item = items[0];
        System.assertEquals(UserInfo.getUserId(), item.ParentId);
        System.assertEquals(''
                + 'Air Temperature: ' + 'd' + '\r\n'
                + 'Pavement Temperature: ' + 'd2' + '\r\n'
                + 'Inches of Rain: ' + 'd3' + '\r\n'
                + 'Inches of Snow: ' + 'd4' + '\r\n'
                + 'Comment: ' + 'd5',
                item.Body
                );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Keith. It worked perfectly...and I was able to understand everything you did. My controller has now been moved from sandbox into production!